# awk or sed to replace html tag

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

i have a large html file with img tags like this

```
<p class="Equation_left_column ParaOverride-2"> <img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-1" src="image/Image353.png" alt=""> </p>
<p class="Equation_left_column ParaOverride-2"> <img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-2" src="image/Image376.png" alt=""> </p>
<p class="Equation_left_column ParaOverride-2"> <img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-3" src="image/Image385.png" alt=""> </p>
```

**and i want to replace every img tag**

```
<img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-." src="image/Image...png" alt="" />
```

with a text which is located in an external file

```
out1.txt
out2.txt
out3.txt
```

**the desired output will be**

```
<p class="Equation_left_column ParaOverride-2">out1.txt (more precisely the text of this file) </p>
<p class="Equation_left_column ParaOverride-2">out2.txt (more precisely the text of this file)</p>
<p class="Equation_left_column ParaOverride-2">out3.txt (more precisely the text of this file)</p>
```

Is there a way, command in awk/sed/etc or a program to achive this?

Comment: I haven't check HTML for long time, the latest version uses `{element}` instead of `<element>`?

Comment: Better show what you tried and where you got stuck in.

Comment: i am sorry. I am newbie here and i replaced the brackets because i couldn't see in the preview my message

Comment: Indent your HTML code with 4 spaces to show the markup properly (or highlight it and press Control and K keys)

Comment: thank you tzhx, i corrected my post!

Comment: Don't put `...`s (or anything else that doesn't exist in your real files) in your sample input and output as that just makes it harder for us to use them to test our code against. If you have multiple rows and/or columns in your real file, just put multiple rows and/or columns in your sample (as you did) - we don't need `...`s to tell us there can more more rows and/or columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
awk '
   FILENAME ~ /Out[0-9]+/ {if(File!=FILENAME)i++;Out[i]=Out[i] $0;File=FILENAME;next}
   /{img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-[0-9]+" src="/{sub(/{img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-[0-9]+" src="[^"]*" alt=""}/, Out[++fi])}
   1' Out*.txt YourFile
```

**Explanation**

- `FILENAME ~ /Out[0-9]+/` select lines that are part of any Out* files (awk work line by line by default)

  - `if(File!=FILENAME)i++` is a index counter incremented every new file name
  - `Out[i]=Out[i] $0` will keep in memory (array) each line of Out file (associate to the previous index)
  - `File=FILENAME;next` remind last file treated (for next iteration) and cycle to next line to treat
- `/{img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-[0-9]+" src="/` when line contain this pattern (and file is the last one due to previous instruction)

  - `sub(/.../, Out[++fi])` replace the pattern by the content of array entry number `fi`. This index is incremented before array is called. The content correspond to loaded files in first series of instruction
- `Out*.txt YourFile` give as input all *Out* files and finnaly your file to treat

Comment: the _idGenOgjectAttribute-3 is not constant. The number 3 is a counter.

Comment: changed to use any number

Comment: So...  Having a blob of code is one thing, but what about explaining what your code does how it addresses the challenge expressed in the question? A great answer is *educational*.

Comment: My file with the text (html) is YourFile that is tt.txt. I tried the above awk '
   FILENAME ~ /out[0-9]+/ {if(File!=FILENAME)i++;out[i]=out[i] $0;File=FILENAME;next}
   /{img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-[0-9]+" src="/{sub(/{img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-[0-9]+" src="[^"]*" alt=""}/, out[++fi])}
   1' out*.txt tt.txt but nothing happens. I only see the content of tt.txt in the terminal.

Comment: you use `out.*` i specify `Out.*`, you need to change any occurrence of out to be consistent with the code

Comment: i changed and i end up with the same result. By the way the command is running if i remove the { from the two {img class="_idGenObjectAttribute and the } after the alt="". Now i have two problems...first problem is the substitution starts from Out100.txt and goes (twice) to 100, 101,101, 102,102, 103,103...221 (i have 221 files) and the second is the above command deletes special characters from the Out files, like &

Comment: try escaping the `{` and `}`. On my system it works without escape but could depend on awk version